# Addind stats to player + overlap method

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Here is my code. I would like my player to have some stats but I'm not really sure what I should do.

I'm pretty new to coding and I think I should add 'something' to player (like, player.life) and it seems to work. But when my player hit the second mushroom (cfr combat at the end of the code) it doesn't log the expected "player life is 470" in the console.

I think the problem could come from the `lifeHitted` variable.

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, '', {
    preload: preload,
    create: create,
    update: update
});
var player;

function preload() {
    game.load.image('square', 'assets/poulpe.png');
    game.load.image('platform', 'assets/platform.png');
    game.load.image('background', 'assets/background.png');
    game.load.image('mushroom', 'assets/mushroom.png');


}

var platforms;

function create() {

    game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'background');
    var text = "Le jeu de Mr Carré.";
    var style = {
        font: "45px Arial",
        fill: "#dddddd",
        align: "center"
    };
    game.add.text(game.world.centerX - 300, 0, text, style);

    //platforms
    platforms = game.add.group();

    ground = platforms.create(0, game.world.height - 90, 'platform');
    ground.scale.setTo(2, 2);
    ground.body.immovable = true;

    //Ledge
    var ledge = platforms.create(145, 350, 'platform');
    ledge.scale.setTo(1, 0.5);
    ledge.body.immovable = true;

    ledge = platforms.create(350, 250, 'platform');
    ledge.scale.setTo(1, 0.5);
    ledge.body.immovable = true;


    //player
    player = game.add.sprite(20, game.world.height - 180, 'square');
    player.scale.setTo(1, 1);
    player.body.bounce.y = 0.2;
    player.body.gravity.y = 6;
    player.body.collideWorldBounds = true;
    player.life = 500;
    currentLife = player.life;

    player.atk = 30;

    //mushroom
    mushroom = game.add.group();
    //mushroom.x= Math.random()*100; 

    mushroom.life = 100;
    mushroom.atk = 15;
    dmg = mushroom.atk;

    mush1 = mushroom.create(200, 250, 'mushroom');
    mush1.body.immovable = true;


    mush2 = mushroom.create(500, 150, 'mushroom');
    mush2.body.immovable = true;

    jumpCount = 0;





}

function update() {

    game.physics.collide(player, platforms);
    game.physics.collide(mushroom, platforms);
    game.physics.overlap(player, mush1, scaleUpPlayer, null, this);
    game.physics.overlap(player, mush2, scaleDownPlayer, null, this);

    function scaleUpPlayer(player, mush) {
        mush.kill();
        player.scale.setTo(2, 2);
        player.x = 210;
        player.y = 200;
    }

    function scaleDownPlayer(player, mush) {
        mush.kill();
        player.scale.setTo(1, 1);
        player.x = 500;
        player.y = 150;
    }


    //jump
    console.log('rrr');
    var jumpKey = game.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Keyboard.UP);
    // A chaque fois que UP est pressé, on lance la fonction jumpCheck()
    jumpKey.onDown.add(jumpCheck);

    function jumpCheck() {
        if ((jumpCount < 1) && (player.body.touching.down)) {
            jump1();
            console.log("jumpCount =" + jumpCount);
            console.log("Vitesse =" + player.body.velocity.y);
            //attention, remettre jumpCount à zéro si on touche le sol
//            if(player.body.touching.down) {
//                jumpCount = 0;
//            }
        }

        //double jump
        if ((jumpCount == 1) && (!player.body.touching.down)) {
            jump2();
            console.log("jumpCount =" + jumpCount);
            console.log("Vitesse =" + player.body.velocity.y);

        }

        //debug
        else if (jumpCount >= 2  ) {
            console.log("jumpCount =" + jumpCount);
            console.log("Vitesse =" + player.body.velocity.y);
        }
    }

    function jump1() {
        console.log("jump1");
        jumpCount++;
        player.body.velocity.y = -320;
    }

    function jump2() {
        console.log("jump2");
        jumpCount = 0;
        player.body.velocity.y = -150;

    }

    //movement
    player.body.velocity.x = 0;

    if (game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.LEFT)) {
        player.body.velocity.x = -350;
    } else if (game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.RIGHT)) {
        player.body.velocity.x = 350;
    }

    //Combat
    game.physics.overlap(player, mushroom, testDmg, null, this);

    function testDmg(){
        if(game.physics.overlap(player, mushroom)){
            lifeHitted = player.life - dmg;

            if(lifeHitted <= 0){
            console.log("Le player meurt.");
            player.kill();
            //die();
            }

            if(lifeHitted > 0){
                console.log("player life is:" + lifeHitted);

            }  
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: are you sure that this line returns true? if(game.physics.overlap(player, mushroom)) you dont need it anyways because the function testDmg only triggers on overlap

Answer (score 0):

The `overlap` function for Phaser is defined with the type of physics engine used:

```
game.physics.arcade.overlap(player, mushroom, testDmg, null, this);
```

The handler function for the overlap requires the two objects that are overlapping as parameters. `testDmg` should be defined like this:

```
function testDmg (player, mushroom) {
    // Subtract the mushroom's attack from the player's life
    player.life = player.life - mushroom.atk;

    if(player.life <= 0){
        console.log("Le player meurt.");
        player.kill();
        //die();
    }

    if(player.life > 0){
        console.log("player life is:" + player.life);
    }  
}
```